# Operation amplifier circuit input potential

Tags: comparator

[image]

How do you find the potential at A and B? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: What do you know about resistor voltage dividers?

Comment: Are you sure this circuit is correct?

Comment: A clue, the inverting and non-inverting inputs take negligible current, assume zero and you will be close enough.  Also what are your thoughts?  We need to see some effort and context before we help.

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no feedback, you can simply calculate the voltage division: 9V*12k/(12k+15k) and 9V*3k/(3k+12k).

---

Ok, bit of explanation: you are probably confused, because you learned, that the inputs of an opamp are on the same potential. This only applies, if there is a negative feedback line, which allows the opamp to increase or decrease the output voltage until the inputs are on the same potential.

In this case you do not have a negative feedback, it is an open-loop circuit, basically a comparator. The opamp switches the output to +9V if the + input is higher than the -, and to GND if the - higher than the + (assuming the open-loop gain is high enough, otherwise just multiply the (Vin+ - Vin-) with the open loop gain). But the inputs do not have to be on the same potential since the output is not connected to the negative input.

Comment: From that answer the TO will probably learn nothing. Try to explain it instead of just giving him to formulas.

Comment: No, the inputs will **not** have the same voltage if you have feedback, they will have the same voltage if you have **negative feedback**.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score -2):

Use voltage divider formula, You can get more details at

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider

Comment: As jusaca mentioned in a comment on another answer, try to explain the process, rather than just giving formulas. This way, the OP can learn more rather than having everything handed to them

Comment: Yup..Understood

Comment: Hi, (a) As required by [this site rule](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/referencing), when you include something in an answer (e.g. photo, image or text) which isn't your original work, you need to properly reference (cite) it. That image seems to have come from somewhere else, so can you please edit your answer and add a link back to the original web page? (b) However, wherever it came from, that image seems to be wrong. There are two labels \$V_{R1}\$, but the lower one should be \$V_{R2}\$! There are better (at least correct) images on other sites...

Comment: @SamGibson Updated as requested, added new and I think this is better one.